# How to properly create non-persistant repositories in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to store resources data in-memory (e.g. in a *Map*, non persistent) in a Spring Boot RESTful web service. I am new to Spring (Boot) and I am not sure what is the preferred approach to do this.

Is creating a *Repository* (`@Repository`) containing the resources the proper way to do this or is it preferred to create a *Service*, a *Component* or use another approach?

Let's say I want to have Todos with many-to-many relationships with Tags as below:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/todos")
public class TodoController {
  @Autowired
  private TodoRepository todoRepository;
  @Autowired
  private TagRepository tagRepository;

  ...
}
```

Is it ok to reconstruct the relationships in the Controller class? Should this happen in an intermediate *TodoService* class?

Comment: why do you want to use repository here

Comment: I do not specifically want to use a _Repository_. I just thought that this was the preferred way to do it from the various examples I found. The only constraint I have is that the same data classes should be accessed from multiple _Controllers_.

Comment: If you want to hold something in memory, just annotate that something (or its surrounding class) with `@Component`. Every time you start your application, @Component candidate will be scanned and corresponding bean will be living into context while application is running. You can always get it from context then.

Comment: @NathanHughes The goal was to make a minimalistic application for learning purpose. I ended up using an H2 in-memory DB with JPA as the default _CrudRepository_ based on `java.util.Map` was too limited for relational data.

Comment: That sounds like the best choice. H2 is great and spring boot makes it easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion on that is pretty straightforward.

If you are doing a basic CRUD application with not a lot of knowledge, but just a way to interact with a Database, then you don't really need to rely on a `Service`, and then yes, having a dependency from your `Controller` to your `Repository` is good.

Let's take an example: When you add a new Todo to your DB, do you always create a new Tag ? If yes, then maybe those two Entities are linked together and should be adressed by a central way, a service. This way, you ensure the person creating Todo will also create the associated Tags. But if those 2 Entities have nothing in common, then keeping them separated works just fine.

About your other questions, the `Repository` thing. You can easily code what you have in mind. In spring, if you look at the code of the annotation `@Repository`, you will see that it is nothing more than a `@Component`. The term `Repository` is only here to help you and your team understanding your code base by easily identifying the role of each class. By definition, a `Repository` is an access to your Domain object, in your case `Todo`. No matter what is the persistance system behind that, this is just an access to your Domain Object.

Here is an example of you can do this.

```
public interface TodoRepository {
    int save(Todo todo);

    Todo findById(int totoId);
}

@Repository
public class InMemoryTodoRepository implements TodoRepository {
    private Map<int, Todo> todos = new HashMap<>();

    public Todo save(Todo todo) {
        int newId = // generate new Id;
        todos.put(newId, todo)
        return newId;
    }

    public Todo findById(int totoId) {
        return todos.get(todoId);
    }
}
```

This way, when you will to change your InMemorySystem to a database of I don't know what, you will just have to make a new class implementing the interface, and you will be good to go, a.k.a **Low coupling**

Answer (score 1):

Repositories are used with JDBC (or JPS, etc) to help you talk to a DB (persistent, like SQL, or in-memory, like H2). If you're not doing that, then you don't need a repository interface.

If you're storing info non-permanently and want to be able to inject that, I'd put that `Map` into a service class, as an instance variable. Then you can inject the service and access that `Map` wherever.

The pattern that I prefer is to inject the services into the controller, have very little in the controller other than the call to the service layer and the construction of the `HTTPResponse`, and put all of the logic into the service. (I would inject the repository/ies into the service to handle any DB interaction, but in your case, those service methods would interact with your map instance variable)/